# How to install Linux Mint through terminal?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

The issue I'm facing is that the graphical interface provided with Mint 13 Cinnamon isn't detecting my partition table and my other Operating System. However, when I use cfdisk, I do see those partitions. So, I created partitions for Linux using cfdisk. But even then, the installer won't detect those partitions. So I'm wondering is there a manual way to install using terminal?

Comment: A Mint 13 installer that uses a text user interface versus a graphics user interface is not going to make any difference.  Both installers are going to use the exact same back-end routines to try to read the partition table.  What is this "other OS"?  Is it Windows?  What does `cfdisk` say about the partition table? Is it a GUID partition table rather than the venerable MBR?

Comment: @sawdust It is Windows 8. `cfdisk` does list those partitions. `fdisk` lists those as `exFat`. It is GUID partition table, not MBR. Also I believe, there's some issue of BIOS vs UEFI. As of now, I'm going to try Mint 14 to see if there's some change.